# Selecting items from database

Tags: sql-server

I'm currently working on a shopping cart, for the admin side I'm trying to get all the orders (and their items) that have no shipped yet. I'm using the following stored procedure but it's not working the way I intend, it's pulling name, invoice, price and such for each item in the cart, what I'm wanting is to pull the order info once, then list all the items (with their quantity and price) for each order.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_GetOrdersNotShipped 
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    BEGIN TRY
        SELECT
            p.ProductName AS 'Name',
            o.OrderId AS 'OrderId',
            o.InvoiceNumber AS 'Invoice',
            o.OrderTotal AS 'Total',
            oi.ProductQuantity AS 'Quantity'
        FROM
            Products p INNER JOIN OrderItems oi ON p.ProductId = oi.ProductId
            INNER JOIN Orders o on oi.OrderId = o.OrderId
        WHERE
            o.IsShipped = 0
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        DECLARE @ErrorNumber INT = ERROR_NUMBER();
        DECLARE @ErrorLine INT = ERROR_LINE();
        DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000) = ERROR_MESSAGE();
        DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT = ERROR_SEVERITY();
        DECLARE @ErrorState INT = ERROR_STATE();

        PRINT 'Actual error number: ' + CAST(@ErrorNumber AS VARCHAR(10));
        PRINT 'Actual line number: ' + CAST(@ErrorLine AS VARCHAR(10));

        RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState);
    END CATCH
END
GO
```

Comment: Can you post a sample result you are looking for and what you are currently getting?

Comment: Are you saying you only want 1 row with the order information and then all the rows with the line items? That is a bit strange. You would either need two queries, or a rather strange union version. Also, you should avoid using the sp_ prefix. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: Your recordset is probably coming back the way it should (with the header info repeated for each detail line) .  At your presentation layer (SSRS, Crystal, etc.) you can then specify showing the header info once and the detail beneath it, until next change in header, then repeat.  As @SeanLange said, to have one recordset take this form would require a very unpleasant union.

Comment: What does your desired result set look like?   What columns should it have?